# Gradle build never stops in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android Studio project. When i compile it using **Build -> make project** menu the build take around 30 seconds. But when I launch my project using the **"run app"** or the **"debug app"** button the gradle build never stops. The process is stucked on "Gradle build running".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had nothing to do with Gradle. It was because of some files I had in the assets folder, I removed these files and it works now. Gradle was looping trying to build again and again.

These files were created when I opened a Realm database I had in the assets folder using Realm Studio :

- default.realm.lock
- default.realm.note
- default.realm.management

I guess it's kind of metadata files used by Realm Studio. They are always created in the same directory of the opened database.